# What does k-means centroid chart in rapid miner actually mean (in layman's terms)?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, k-means, rapidminer, unsupervised-learning

Could anyone explain to me what does the centroid chart of k-means in Rapid Miner exactly mean? 
I know this chart visualizes the centroid values of each feature with respect to the cluster but I need some more expert explanations from experts.

for example, I have questions like, why the "AGE" feature from cluster 0 have positive centroid and cluster 1 have negative centroid?

[image: This is the K-means centroid chart]

Thanks in advance for your time :)

Image Source = https://optimalbi.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/RapidMiner_Graph-1024x588.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the **essential details of each cluster.**

The Centroid Chart shows the values for the cluster centroids in a parallel chart.

You can see:

- the size of each cluster
- the centroid values of the features within each cluster

> for example, I have questions like, why the "AGE" feature from cluster
>   0 have positive centroid and cluster 1 have negative centroid?

**Well, inside each cluster you have some samples and these samples are characterized by some features like Age. So this means that the average value of the Age features of the samples that belong to Cluster 1 is -0.2.**